# Can I use 2 different nations' passports in China to circumvent visa restrictions?

Tags: visas, passports, china

I am in China and want to stay longer. I already have the maximum amount of  visas in my passport A (I can get only 3 times "one month port office visa" from Hong Kong) so I cannot get an additional visa using that passport.  However I also have passport B, from a different nation and my surname differs by one letter, which I could use.

But I only have one set of fingerprints.  So using passport B, will they know I am the same person at the border? Could I have any problem?

Comment: This is the first time I hear of a limit on visas from Hong Kong. My passport is full of them. I'm currently in Shenzhen on a 2-entry visa. When I use both entries, I'll another one, and another one, and, etc... Just go back to HK and get a 2-entry visa.

Comment: Good to hear that. Thank You. I got that information both from agency and agent. I am talking about the visa issued at port visa office. So I assume that your visa is from consulate, right?

Comment: To dda. Could you please let know where or how to get the visa that you mentioned in your comment. It would be very helpful not just for me. Thank You very much.

Comment: @dda did you see the last request (perhaps not, as there was no ping). Are you able to add your info as an answer (and ping me and I'll upvote).

Answer (score 4):

As asked in the comments, an extension on my original comment, as an answer.

This is the first time I hear of a limit on visas from Hong Kong. My passport is full of them. I'm currently in Shenzhen on a 2-entry visa. When I use both entries, I'll get another one, and another one, and, etc... (NB: that was at the time of the comment. I have used up both entries, and will now get a new one).

Just go back to HK and get a 2-entry visa.

I usually get my 2-entry, 30 days per visit, visas in Hong Kong via a travel agency, one of the big chains. The reason is twofold:

1. The visa section at the China Ressources Building is a circus on the best of days, and the staff there is inflexible and unfriendly. And since France is still on China's shit list, we have to provide a lot more papers than travellers from many other countries. And even if you want to travel to Shenzhen only, they still ask for plane tickets. And travel insurance. Travel agencies get special treatment from the visa section. They have special counters (although in the case of French citizens, again, it doesn't really matter, as we can only get the regular processing time, 5 working days. We cannot get express 1-day visas, so no rush, really...). Their applications are treated much more leniently than individual applications. Mostly because of (2):
2. Travel agencies can produce "real fake" hotel and airplane reservations, proof of insurance, etc... They make real bookings, submit the paperwork, and cancel everything after that. So you show up, fill out a form, give photos, quite a bit of money, your passport, and they do the rest. Works like a charm. It's just quite expensive...